# Revert position of draggable item with margin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created a simplified fiddle for my problem. When you drag the item it is reverted to the wrong position which is caused by the margin. How can I do a workaround for this problem? http://jsfiddle.net/pZF27/1/

HTML:

```
<img id="image" alt="Image" />
```

CSS:

```
#image{
    cursor: move; 
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#image').draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper:'clone',
    cursorAt: { 
        top: -40
    },
});
```

PS: I don't know how to style the Code, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the `cursorAt` option and apply the same margin to the drag helper

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pZF27/2/)**

```
#image, .ui-draggable {
    cursor: move;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```